# Looking for an Alternative to Deprecated onBackPressed() Method in Java for Android Development

Tags: android-studio

I'm currently working on implementing back button functionality in my Android application, and I've come across the deprecated **`onBackPressed()`** method. I'm looking for an alternative solution to handle the back button press event in my Java code. Any advice or examples would be greatly appreciated. Thank you in advance for your help!

Alternative code

Any insights or examples demonstrating how to handle the back button press event effectively using Java would be greatly appreciated. Thank you for your time and assistance in resolving this issue